# Configuration to publish ASP.NET CORE projects using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, .net-core

I have configured for other projects to publish the .Net project using Jenkins and they all worked well. I'm using this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" %WORKSPACE%\Source\test1.sln /T:Clean /T:Rebuild.
```

But this didn't work for ASP.NET core project using Jenkins to build and publish. Manually, I can build and publish from Visual Studio 2017. Does anyone here know how to configure Jenkins to build and publish ASP.Net CORE project using Jenkins.

Comment: I don't believe .Net core uses MSBuild 14. You need to use the [new CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x)

Comment: [Using .NET Core SDK and tools in Continuous Integration (CI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/using-ci-with-cli)

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins should not be the problem here. I can confirm that my Jenkins jobs are building Net Core 2.0 solutions. You need MSBuild "15" which can be downloaded [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) (build tools for VS 2017). After installation, the default location should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`.

And yours can be changed into something like this:

```
"& C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" %WORKSPACE%\Source\test1.sln /T:Clean /T:Rebuild.
```

Furthermore, you can check the changes here with the build tool [at Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/releases).